# difference in top command and gnome-system-terminal applet

Tags: gnome, ram, top

I am running xubuntu 12.04, and i find that TOP command reports 900MB RAM usage where as gnome-system-terminal applet graphically shows only 300MB RAM usage.
Why the values are differently reported?What is now the correct thing? and Why TOP reports it that way.

Thanks,
Harish Pathangay

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176676/difference-between-the-results-of-the-top-command-and-system-monitor-why?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

After googling and posting the question in forums, i came to understand that TOP reports total used = buffers+cache area.
gnome-system-terminal displays only individual process memory comsumption.
I used the free command to get the individual process memory comsumption.
All is fine. My understanding got corrected.

Thanks,
Harish Pathangay